# Am I imagining this or did I just found one of the oldest "hidden" erotic artworks ever?

Tags: iron-age, norway

I was just wiki-walking around my country's (Netherlands) history when I stumbled upon this topic:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ger%C3%B0r

She is the wife of the god Freyr, whom apparently the Frisians and the Frisiavones were a cultus worshipping him.

Now I looked at the [gullgubber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullgubber) of that page and the texts of [this image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullgubber#mediaviewer/File%3aGoldgubb.jpg) on the Gerdur page says the two figures (representing Freyr and Gerdur according to the Dutch page of Gerdur) have a "leafy bough" between them. But perhaps it's just my dirty mind but I immediately thought "That's no leafy bough! That's a ... and it's not between two people but between a pair of ..."

I just want confirmation from a historian to see if I'm the first one to notice this and whether or not this was indeed the artists intention ;-).

Comment: Historians are not notably shy in describing phallic, priapic or other sexual motifs in ancient objects.  Sometimes a leafy bough is just a leafy bough.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. In general, the motif of a man and woman embracing is very common on guldgubbar, but there is nothing overtly sexual about them. Occasionally, there will be some kind of tree behind them. A Google image search of "guldgubber" will give you several examples

This does not mean that this could not be an exception. However, I found a clearer picture of the same guldgubbe [here](http://www.tjeldsundhistorielag.no/index.php/severdigheter/oldtidsfunnimuseum/vikingetiden). I have to say that I can see neither leafy boughs nor anything else vaguely phallic.

If Viking age artists (which, admittedly, were a few centuries later) wanted to depict something a phallos, they could be explicit, see [this](http://historiska.se/upptack-historien/foremal/frejstatyett/) statue, likely of Frey.

Finally, any sort of identification with people or gods from myths and legends can not be taken as anything more than guesses.